# Access related models/tables to inner join query in cakephp

Tags: php, mysql, sql, cakephp

I have this `inner` `join` query in a paginated model called `Application`

`Application` has many `AssignedExploration`

`AssignedExploration` belongs to `Exploration`

`Exploration` belongs to `ExplorationCategory`

`ExplorationCategory` belongs to `Season`

My query so far is:

```
$session_condition = array(
    'table' => 'assigned_explorations',
    'alias' => 'AssignedExploration',
    'type' => 'INNER',
    'conditions' => array(
        'AssignedExploration.application_id = Application.id',
        'OR' => array(
            array('AssignedExploration.label' => $this->request->named['filter_session'])
        )
    )
);
```

I would like to add another query inside the `OR` that will get `applications` which has a `Season.name = fall`

I've tried adding `array('Season.name' => 'fall')` :

```
$session_condition = array(
    'table' => 'assigned_explorations',
    'alias' => 'AssignedExploration',
    'type' => 'INNER',
    'conditions' => array(
        'AssignedExploration.application_id = Application.id',
        'OR' => array(
            array('AssignedExploration.label' => $this->request->named['filter_session']),
            array('Season.name' => 'fall')
        )
    )
);
```

But no luck. Seems like Season is not recognized by `AssignedExploration`.

I would like to nest from `AssignedExploration` to `Exploration` to `ExplorationCategory` and to `Season`

And I don't have any idea on how to make it thru `inner` `join` query via cakephp.

Thanks in advanced.

EDIT: query as of now:

```
INNER JOIN 
    `ntc_development`.`assigned_explorations` AS `AssignedExploration` ON ( 
        `AssignedExploration`.`application_id` = `Application`.`id` 
         AND 
         `AssignedExploration`.`label` = 'fall'
     )
```

Comment: can you write whole query?
you have to use two inner join and use conditions outside join

Comment: `INNER JOIN `ntc_development`.`assigned_explorations` AS `AssignedExploration` ON (`AssignedExploration`.`application_id` = `Application`.`id` AND `AssignedExploration`.`label` = 'fall')` but that's just the condition that I have right now. I would like to nest up to Season to add another condition thanks

Comment: This question seems to be incomplete You're trying applying conditions to the season model but it's not mentioned anywhere in the code in the question. It's also not obvious how `$season_condition` is used

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->paginate['Application'] = array(
                'recursive' => -1,
                'joins' => array(
                    array(
                        'table' => 'assigned_explorations',
                        'alias' => 'AssignedExploration',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'foreignKey' => true,
                        'conditions' => array('AssignedExploration.application_id = Application.id')
                    ),
                    array(
                        'table' => 'seasons',
                        'alias' => 'Season',
                        'type' => 'inner',
                        'foreignKey' => true,
                        'conditions' => array('Season.id = Application.season_id') # whats your foregin key
                    ),                                         
                ),
                'fields' => array(),
                'conditions' => array('Season.name' => 'fail'),
            );
```